# Valid Xpath but empty div returned - Amazon scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am having some hard time retrieving information from Amazon pages with a small scraping script. Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import random
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




sleep_time_min = 5
sleep_time_max = 10




### INFORMATION FOR PROXY, UA & INFO ROTATION ###

user_agent_list = ['Mozilla/5.0 CK={} (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36',
                   'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)','Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.29 Safari/525.13',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.27 Safari/525.13']

opts = Options()
user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
opts.add_argument("user-agent="+user_agent)    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='XXXXXXXX', options=opts)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00J4B0S4O')
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

sleep_time_range = range(sleep_time_min,sleep_time_max)
sleep_time = random.choice(sleep_time_range)
time.sleep(sleep_time)  


#Extract seller rank & sales category
try:     
    rank = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="detailBullets_feature_div"]/ul[@class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-none detail-bullet-list"]/li/span[@class="a-list-item"]/span[@class="a-text-bold"]')
    #rank = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="detail-bullets_feature_div"]').text
    #rank = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="a-page"]').text
except:
    rank = "NA"
    
    print(rank)
         
driver.close()
```

So basically I am trying to retrieve the following info on the page:

```
Best Sellers Rank: #711 in Grocery & Gourmet Food (See Top 100 in Grocery & Gourmet Food)
#1 in Grapeseed Oils
```

Then slice it so I can store ranks & categories into variables.

Here is my problem, my xpath keeps returning empty results despite all my efforts. I have left so other xpath I used in the code (i.e. high level divs, but the results is unfortunately the same).

Unfortunately I fail to see why those outcomes remain empty. Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot for the help here

Comment: Try `find_elements_by_css_selector`. I've found that searching by xpath with `@class="space separated values"` does not always work as the values may not appear in the same order. Hence my preference for, e.g., `div.aclass.anotherclass.yetanother` as the CSS selector does not care about the order.

Comment: Try this, ```driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div > .detail-bullet-list')[0]```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm see the same outcome :/ (tried several version of this piece of code).

But to your point @JustinEzequiel, even when trying the master div a-page, the problem remains, so  I am not sure this is a matter of order here

Comment: How about this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-list-item'][contains(.,'Best Sellers Rank:')]")`?

Comment: Same unfortunately, still empty :/

Comment: If you still don't get required result using the xpath I've suggested, your script surely is unable to get desired response. Make sure you go through the response the script comes up with in order to check whether what you are looking for is available there, otherwise no locator will help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes definitely, but that's actually where I need help. I am happy to change anything or investigate more, but at this point I fail to see what I'm missing in the soup / response that is causing this, that's my main problem actually

Comment: Did you check whether `Best Sellers Rank:` is available in `driver.page_source`?

Comment: Yes confirming I catch it with the page_source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it the ugly way, not very beautiful but working :)

```
  try:
        rank_main = soup.find_all('span','a-list-item')
        rank_main = str(rank_main)
        rank_main = rank_main.split("(<a href")[0]
        rank_main = rank_main.split("#")[1]
        rank_main = rank_main.replace("amp;","")
        rank1bis_nb = rank_main.split('in')[0]
        rank1bis_cat = rank_main.split('in ')[1]
    except:
        rank1bis_nb = "NA"
        rank1bis_cat = "NA"



    try:
        rank_raw = soup.find_all('ul','a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical zg_hrsr')
        rank_raw = str(rank_raw)
        
        rank_raw = rank_raw.replace("[","")
        rank_raw = rank_raw.replace("]","")
        rank_raw = rank_raw.replace("#","")
        rank_raw = re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', rank_raw)
        rank_raw = rank_raw.strip()
        rank_raw = rank_raw.replace("amp;","")
        

        rank2bis_nb = rank_raw.split('in')[0]
        rank2bis_cat = rank_raw.split('in ')[1]

    except:
        rank2bis_nb = "NA"
        rank2bis_cat = "NA"
```